# 'Employee Profiles' or 'Employees Profiles' or 'Employees' Profiles'?

Tags: grammatical-number

I had a spat with a coworker. We are compiling a software feature list.
One of the entries was the "Employee Profile". However, we wanted to write it down in plural. So, which one should it be?

> 1 - Employee Profiles
>   2 - Employees Profiles
>   3 - Employees' Profiles

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the following:

> 1 - Correct
>   2 - Incorrect
>   3 - Works, too

Comment: I agree with your assessment in that both 1 and 3 are fine and 2 is plain wrong. My own preference would be for 3 over 1, though, since the periphrastic genitive, *profiles of employees,* makes perfect sense as a substitution here. Pressing a noun into service as an attributive adjective, as in 1, works, but the overuse of that device is a hallmark of bad style. When it *is* done in English, in any case, it is not to be inflected plural to match the base noun. No one brings "bottles openers" to a picnic.

Comment: Good, except the uncalled-for and unsubstantiated _opinion_ about "bad style".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 and 3 in this instance would be correct.

1) 'Employee Profile' is a complete noun phrase with 'employee' - in this instance - not a noun in its own right but a '[noun adjunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)'. It is playing the part of a modifier for the subject noun 'Profile' and it is only this word that would take the plural.

3) Also correct but for a different reason. Here they are two separate nouns. 'Employee' in this instance is taking a possessive which splits the complete noun phrase seen in choice 1. So for proper agreement both would need to be conjugated to the plural.